# I am looking for a show that once on Netflix between 2015-2018 about a kid who gets/has fire powers from some entity

Tags: science-fiction-genre

The show was a mini series and was 3d animated(I think) I also remember the final episode have a large fight with some red humanoid monster.

Comment: This is very thin on detail. Could you provide more details if you remember them: Which language did you watch this in? Which country? Anything elese that you can remember could potentially help with an ID.

Comment: I watched in the us in English and I also remember an episode where there is a battle in a dojo of somekind

Comment: I also can't really remember what time it was taken off but it was a short show with around 3-7 episodes

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.